# Deployment of vCenter Operations Manager failing

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I recently downloaded a trial of vCenter Operations Manager to deploy to our ESXi 4 environment. I wanted to test this software to see if it would be useful, but I cannot seem to get it working. First, I tried to import the .ova into VirtualBox, which fails:

Failed to import appliance VMware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp.ovf.

Could not verify the content of 'VMware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp.mf' against the available files (VERR_MANIFEST_FILE_MISMATCH).

Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: Appliance
Interface: IAppliance {3059cf9e-25c7-4f0b-9fa5-3c42e441670b}

I download an sha1 verifier and got the following results:

> fciv.exe -add VMware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp -sha1
>   cb1daf36ef679b3a91f53ceadffaff2800dc3321 vmware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp\VMwar
>   e-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-data.vmdk
>   cb1daf36ef679b3a91f53ceadffaff2800dc3321 vmware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp\VMwar
>   e-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-data2.vmdk
>   b7b963b59bae0aa3df911954007e81648492f63c vmware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp\VMwar
>   e-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-system.vmdk
>   b0bd7f733f55866da1a888eeace24d3c58d9511b vmware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp\VMwar
>   e-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp.cert
>   a9459d02f72559d840c30fa769f3649dbc3ebd55 vmware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp\VMwar
>   e-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp.mf
>   070574d5efffb201bff8ad3166ad456a7ceef2d6 vmware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp\VMwar
>   e-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp.ovf

SHA1 hashes as shown in the manifest file referenced:

SHA1 (VMware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-data.vmdk) = cb1daf36ef679b3a91f53ceadffaff2800dc3321
SHA1 (VMware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-data2.vmdk) = cb1daf36ef679b3a91f53ceadffaff2800dc3321
SHA1 (VMware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-system.vmdk) = b7b963b59bae0aa3df911954007e81648492f63c
SHA1 (VMware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp.ovf) = 070574d5efffb201bff8ad3166ad456a7ceef2d6

So I thought "the file must be corrupted". I then hashed the actual .ova file itself:
`SHA1 = ae8f10fe1b7f51b10fa7c1945e71434d33b0f8e3 vmware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp.ova

MD5 = 89bddfd645b86ebe16c6102b631a4b91 vmware-vcops-5.7.0.0-1073531-vapp.ova`

From their website:
SHA1SUM(¹): ae8f10fe1b7f51b10fa7c1945e71434d33b0f8e3
MD5SUM(¹): 89bddfd645b86ebe16c6102b631a4b91

So, all hashes match up and yet it refuses to import. So, I decided to import it into the vSphere client and get the following:

Line 68: Unsupported element "VirtualSystemCollection"

I'm at a loss here...if anyone has any ideas please let me know!

Comment: I believe you need to deploy into a VMware infrastructure.

Comment: I did. When I deployed to our ESXi host I got that "unsupported element" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Deployment and Configuration Guide vCenter Operations Manager 5](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vcops-5-installation-guide.pdf)

> vCenter Operations Manager is a vApp that you import and deploy with a vCenter Server system.

So you will need to connect with your vSphere Client to a vCenter and then deploy the OVA to that environment.

Comment: Arg, I was afraid of that since we don't have vCenter configured right now. I'm still curious why VirtualBox can't import it either.

Comment: @NathanC it's because vcops is actually a v-app (resource pool) there are two VMs in it, the data analyzer and the UI, and VirtualBox doesn't get that there are two VMs, it tries to import it as one.